# Java swing add text on text area

Tags: java, swing

How can I add (not set) a text using a button on a text area. For example: if I have one button which add "Hello" and secound button will add " World" the result should be Hello World.

Comment: Set the value of the text equal to the original text concatenated with the new text.

Comment: And how should I do that?

Comment: Since this seems like an assignment, I'm trying to avoid giving you an exact answer and instead plant the idea.  In the concept of getters and setters, you can GET the current value and SET the new value accordingly, using the information returned from the GET.

Comment: If you go to the docs, you'll find that there's a method called: [`JTextArea#append`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) which does what you want